# How do exceptions work in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

```
ebool keep_trying= true;
do {
    char fname[80]; // std::string is better
    cout Image "Please enter the file name: ";
    cin Image fname;
    try {
        A= read_matrix_file(fname);
        ...
        keep_trying= false;
    } catch (cannot_open_file& e) {
        cout Image "Could not open the file. Try another one!\n";
    } catch (...)
        cout Image "Something is fishy here. Try another file!\n";
    }
} while (keep_trying);
```

This code is from [Discovering modern c++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134383583). I don't understand what "A" in the try-block stand for and "e"(cannot_open_file& e) in the next catch-block

Comment: Are you reading the book in order?

Comment: I doubt that the book just throws a block of code at you without explaining the concepts. Did you read till the end of the paragraph?

Comment: actually only with this snippet nobody can know what `A` exactly is, it is the return value of some function whose definition you dont tell us ( I am pretty sure that it can be found in the book). You could as well ask what is the meaning of `x` in `x = foo();`

Comment: Yes, the book just throws the code. Yes, I'm reading it in order, I wanted to skipped this part because I don't really get it and when I test the code it doesn't work. Does anyone know what the "e" stand for in the first cath-block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be an incomplete code snippet. You can assume that 'A' is of whatever type that read_matrix_file() returns.  And 'e' is a reference to a cannot_open_file type, which should be defined somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int read_matrix_file(const char* fname, ...)
{
    fstream f(fname);
    if (!f.is_open())
        return 1;
        ...
    return 0;
}
```

"A" is the return value of `int read_matrix_file()` function.

```
struct cannot_open_file {};
void read_matrix_file(const char* fname, ...)
{
   fstream f(fname);
   if(!f.is_open())
   throw cannot_open_file{};
   ...
}
```

'e' is the exception (throw by `void read_matrix_file()` function) we're trying to catch. Basic code actually.
Thanks for your help StackOverflow!

All code are from "**Discovering moder C++**". See question for link.